# Address versus Value at Address

Tags: assembly, kernel

I am currently dealing with a problem relating to some kernel-mode code referencing `%gs`. Here’s what’s going on:

I have a [fairly large structure](https://github.com/Andromeda-OS/Kernel/blob/master/osfmk/i386/cpu_data.h#L121-L247) which is stored in the `%gs` register. I am trying to get/set the `cpu_active_thread` value from that structure, which happens to be at offset 0x8 inside that structure. In other words, I am trying to get/set `%gs:0x8`. The problem is, when I get the value, the result is the literal value 0x8. (As this is not a valid address, I am crashing later on.) How can I change this so that I am getting the value eight bytes into the structure based in `%gs`?

If you need to know how I am getting the data out of the structure, [I am using these macros](https://github.com/Andromeda-OS/Kernel/blob/master/osfmk/i386/cpu_data.h#L258-L283). Thanks!

Edit: I am using clang. The macros above are used as such:

```
static inline thread_t
get_active_thread(void)
{
    CPU_DATA_GET(cpu_active_thread,thread_t)
}
```

Comment: A "large structure stored in the GS register"?? Isn't GS just a 16-bit segment selector?!

Comment: @KerrekSB I think OP means "the structure offset by `%gs`"

Comment: Also, have you verified that the generated assembly actually uses the `%gs` selector? And that `%gs` points to a valid data segment at whatever offset?

Comment: Please please show the code where you're using the macros. What compiler are you using, gcc or clang?

Comment: The code declares thread_t to be of type "inline", what is type "inline" ? Were these macros intended to be used with the tool set (compiler) that you are using?

Comment: @rcgldr: This is a function declaration. The return type is `thread_t`; `inline` is a modifier on the function.

Comment: @wjk - Having the declaration split into two lines misled me. It makes sense now that I see it. Can you have the compiler output assembly code to verify that it's using %gs segment register? Are you sure the offset is 8 (running in 32 bit mode as opposed to 64 bit mode)?

Comment: They have a comment in there which says *Everyone within the osfmk part of the kernel can use the fast inline versions of these routines.* Do you know what `osfmk` means? Are you part of that? It sounds like kernel code can use that trick, but not client code.