# IA32 GS.base Usage

Tags: assembly, kernel, x86-64

I am trying to write a custom kernel that uses `%gs` as a segment base to load and store CPU-local information under x86_64. (I am using QEMU 2.1.0 to run my kernel, if that matters.) [I previously asked about this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25294924/address-versus-value-at-address), but since then I discovered more information, and the changes don’t quite fit into my earlier question.

I am loading the address of a CPU-local data structure using the `IA32_GS_BASE` MSR. However, no matter what I do, it seems that the address in the MSR is not being honored. `%gs` still evaluates to zero, and as such I am getting addresses that (a) crash when used and (b) don’t point to the data structure I loaded before.

I have two hypotheses. One is that I need to perform some cache-flushing operation of some sort before the MSR value will be acknowledged. The other is that I am not setting the MSR correctly. However, `IA32_GS_BASE` is *very* poorly documented, and I cannot find any evidence to support either theory.

Any pointers? (No pun intended.)

Comment: You can find a bit more documentation of this MSR in AMD's documentation under it's original name `MSR_GS_BASE`. Have you tried loading `%gs` with a null selector (0) before loading the GS base? There might be stale limits or attributes still in the descriptor cache.

Comment: @RossRidge - Any direct setting of `%gs` results in a triple-fault. I believe that this is because setting the segment directly under x86_64 is invalid. Also, please elucidate more about “stale limits or attributes”.

Comment: Setting `%gs` to zero should never cause a fault. It's also perfectly legal to load the segment registers in long mode, both in the kernel and user mode. In all modes every segment register is backed by a descriptor cache that holds the value of last descriptor loaded. It has a base, a limit and various attributes. Switching processor modes doesn't change the descriptor caches so it's possible that the GS descriptor cache still has limits and an attributes from real mode. They should be ignored in long mode, but that may assume GS was actually loaded once in long mode.

Comment: @RossRidge - `%gs` was zeroed — once, [before changing into long mode](https://github.com/Andromeda-OS/Kernel/blob/master/osfmk/x86_64/start.s#L201-L206). To the extent of my knowledge, it hasn’t been touched since.

Comment: Well, it was changed after entering long mode in the code you linked so it appears that rules out old values in the descriptor cache.

Comment: You should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I have tested with [this piece of code](http://paste.debian.net/115741/) in 64 bit kernel mode, and seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my tests, your problem isn't immediately with `GS` base.
Running in qemu dies with a double fault, that doesn't provide any indication about a `GS` issue. Running with bochs, I don't get any sensible debug output from the code, but I can use the built-in debugger to prove that at least the setting of `GS` base and a read operation works.

```
(0) [0x000000000030d346] 0008:ffffff800030d346 (unk. ctxt): wrmsr                     ; 0f30
<bochs:20> r
rax: 0x00000000_00828c00 rcx: 0x00000000_c0000101
rdx: 0x00000000_ffffff80 rbx: 0xffffff80_00833480
rsp: 0xffffff80_0010bfb0 rbp: 0xffffff80_0010bfb0
rsi: 0xffffff80_0010bf48 rdi: 0xffffff80_00828c00
r8 : 0xffffff80_007dbe03 r9 : 0x00000000_0000007f
r10: 0x00000021_00000000 r11: 0xffffff80_00cf9000
r12: 0x80000000_00c74003 r13: 0x00000000_00000084
r14: 0x00000000_00a33000 r15: 0xffffff80_00c75000
rip: 0xffffff80_0030d346
eflags 0x00000002: id vip vif ac vm rf nt IOPL=0 of df if tf sf zf af pf cf
```

This breakpoint should be in your `_cpu_data_realloc` function, I believe. Looking at the registers, we can see that MSR `0xc0000101` is going to be written with a value of `0xffffff8000828c00`, and that will correctly set `GS` base. Indeed, after a triggered crash bochs is kind enough to confirm this:

```
10725675946i[CPU0 ] |  MSR_GS_BASE:ffffff8000828c00
```

I have placed another breakpoint at a subsequent use of `GS`, not sure where this is in the source code:

```
(0) [0x00000000003232b2] 0008:ffffff80003232b2 (unk. ctxt): mov r14d, dword ptr gs:0x000000000000001c ; 65448b34251c000000
```

Okay so it reads `gs:0x1c`. Testing shows this is zero. To prove that the value is indeed read from the correct memory location, let's set it to something interesting:

```
<bochs:21> page 0xffffff8000828c1c
PML4: 0x0000000000c72023 ps         A pcd pwt S W P
PDPE: 0x0000000000c6e023 ps         A pcd pwt S W P
 PDE: 0x0000000000a7e023 ps         A pcd pwt S W P
 PTE: 0x0000000000828063    g pat D A pcd pwt S W P
linear page 0xffffff8000828000 maps to physical page 0x0000000000828000
<bochs:22> setpmem 0x828c1c 4 0x42424242
```

The load then executes without problem, and indeed loads that value:

```
<bochs:23> s
Next at t=91228625505
(0) [0x00000000003232bb] 0008:ffffff80003232bb (unk. ctxt): lea rdi, qword ptr ds:[rip+5863966] ; 488d3d1e7a5900
<bochs:24> r
rax: 0x00000000_00000000 rcx: 0xffffff80_0087ae80
rdx: 0xffffff80_008bad10 rbx: 0xffffff80_0075b564
rsp: 0xffffff80_0010bde0 rbp: 0xffffff80_0010be10
rsi: 0x00000000_00000072 rdi: 0xffffff80_0075b564
r8 : 0x00000000_00000010 r9 : 0x00000000_00000000
r10: 0x00000000_00000000 r11: 0x00000000_00000000
r12: 0xffffff80_0010bec4 r13: 0x00000000_00000084
r14: 0x00000000_42424242 r15: 0xffffff80_008f2b38
rip: 0xffffff80_003232bb
eflags 0x00000082: id vip vif ac vm rf nt IOPL=0 of df if tf SF zf af pf cf
```

Whatever your problem is, it's probably elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

A few quick searches suggested that a better alternative is to use the [`WRGSBASE`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/WRFSBASE:WRGSBASE.html) instruction. This avoids any mess with MSRs.

If that doesn't work, another alternative would be to set `IA32_KERNEL_GS_BASE` (index 0xC0000102; note the `KERNEL` in the middle) followed by the [`SWAPGS`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SWAPGS.html) instruction.

Comment: `wrgsbase` doesn’t work; all it does is triple-fault the processor. Also, `IA32_KERNEL_GS_BASE` is also being set, but it is my understanding that it doesn’t do anything until the switch to user-mode.

Comment: Correction: `IA32_KERNEL_GS_BASE` won’t be _used_ until user-mode; it can still be _set_ in kernel-mode.

Comment: @wjk looking at the link I provided, `SWAPGS` *requires* kernel mode - as such, `IA32_KERNEL_GS_BASE` will be swapped out with the current GS base by `SWAPGS`.